# Is there a way to get a public storage directory according to mime type?

Tags: android, mime-types

I'm just wondering whether there's a convenient method to do this. We've got [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) defined directories for movies, images, music etc so I'd like to store received files according to their mime types to the right directory.

Of course, I could store everything into Downloads or ask the user but maybe there's a clever way to do it?